# How can I have a switch and after getting out of a case return to the switch being able to choose a different case?

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

How can I have a switch and after getting out of a case return to the switch being able to choose a different case?
I am new to java and would like to know if someone could help me out with this. It's a project I'm working on and have to insert data in a case and output in others. It's like a program to keep track of incomes and earnings of a company. this is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class lab {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Character letra;
        char subswitch;
        int num;
        String[] productos = new String[10];
        int[] codprod = new int[10];
        int[] cant = new int[10];
        int[] precioc [] = new int[10];
        int m=0;
        int isv;
        char pregunta;

        System.out.println("Ingrese su opcion (a/b/c/d/e): ");
        letra=sc.next().charAt(0);
        boolean loop = true;

        do{
            switch(letra){
            case 'a':
            System.out.println("Bienvenido a configuracion");
            System.out.println("Seleccione lo que desea configurar ISV:'e'/Precio de venta:'d'/Descuentos:'f'/Salir:'g'");
            subswitch=sc.next().charAt(0); 
                switch(subswitch) {
                case 'e':
                    System.out.println("Desea asignar un nuevo valor al isv? Y/N");
                    pregunta=sc.next().charAt(0);

                    if(pregunta=='y'|| pregunta=='Y') {
                        System.out.println("ingrese la cantidad que desea asignar al isv");
                        num=sc.nextInt();
                        isv=num/100;
                    } else {
                        isv=15/100;
                    }
                    break;
                case'd':
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    break;
                case 'g':
                System.out.println("Adios");
                break;
                }                   
                break;
            case 'b':
                System.out.println("Bienvenido a compras");
                for(int n=0;n<productos.length;n++){
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del proveedor: ");
                    productos[n]=sc.next();

                    System.out.println("Ingrese el codigo del producto: ");
                    codprod[n]=sc.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad del producto: ");
                    cant[n]=sc.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("Ingrese el precio del producto: ");
                    precioc[n]=sc.nextInt();
                }
                break;
            case 'c':
                break;
            case 'd':
                break;
            case 'e':
                loop=false;
                System.out.println("Adios");
                break;
            }
        } while (loop==true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You enclose the entire `switch` statement in a loop, just like you have. As a note, properly formatting your code makes it much, much easier to read.

Comment: .... and easier to debug!

Comment: Also put the code that changes the "letra" variable inside the loop just before the switch because you're switching on the letra variable.

Comment: Thank you,i was trying to set letra to null after every break and had an error with that. Now setting it before the switch has much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: You'd do it with a loop.